# Crystal Reports Cross-tab overlapping issue

Tags: crystal-reports, report

[image]I need some assistance to diagnose an issue with crystal reports overlapping occurs in one of my reports where Cross tab is being used inside sub-report , the crosstab overlaps the next section, this happen just when we run the report through our web site, while it is working fine in Crystal report designer ,our current version of Crystal run time is 13_0_7 it run  in  32 bit mode , the report was working fine in Crystal 2008 runtime SP3 before we upgrade our system to use the 13_0_7 version.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Can u show us some picture of that "overlap"?

Comment: I have added a picture to my original question, the black frames show the subreports' borders where the cross-tab supposed to be in.

Comment: are the cross-tabs in their own sections?  If not, try adding a new section containing only the cross-tab object.

Comment: @Beth I agree with you. For each cross-tab there should be the same section. if you have it on detail section then `right click`, and `insert section below`. After that you have `detail section a` and `detail section b`

Comment: Thanks guys, My cross-tabs are placed in three different sections,  but I do know the cause of that odd behavior now , in my report I inserted three cross-tabs each of them is in different sections, I placed the first one in the main report and the others I put them in two different subreports , I noticed when I remove the first cross-tab from the main report the overlapping is no longer exist, obviously this is a bug in the runtime, so now to work around this issue I created third subreport and I moved the cross tab that was in the main report into it.

Thanks again

Nirouz